# Load File with Jquery not work on Chrome when run at server (hosting)

Tags: php, jquery

Please tell me where's the code/line have wrong code/write...

```
$(function() {
        $('#link a').click(function() {
            var url = 'media.php' 
            $('#view').load(url);       
            return false;
        }); 
    });
```

in local server this code running normally ...but why when run at server(hosting) nothing happened, the page only show blank page without any text/content show...
(Chrome only)..hope someone can help me

Comment: Any errors in dev tools?

Comment: Is `media.php` file path is correct is server.

Comment: am sure path is correct cozz am try in another browser run with no problems